# What changes should I make to improve my homebrew Circle of the Ent druid subclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, druid, homebrew-review, archetype

I am currently trying to create a custom druid subclass called the Circle of the Ent, inspired by Ents from *The Lord of the Rings*. I really love the concepts, but I do not have any experience with custom classes or how to make them balanced.

**What should I do to improve my custom druid circle? What, if anything, have I done well? How can I make the wording flow better?**

Full info below:

---

### Circle of the Ent

Druids of the Circle of the Ent are attached to the nature around them in everything they do. They feel what the plants feel, and the plants feel what they feel. They are capable of arousing plants to fight but must be careful since they will feel some of the harm done to any plants.

Because of their abnormally deep connection with plants, Circle of the Ent druids take on many of their characteristics including appearance, movement, and a steadier world view.

#### Circle Spells

Your understanding of the flora around you and deeper connection to and awareness of the living world grants you access to certain spells.

At 3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th level you gain access to the spells listed for that level in the table below. Once you gain access to one of these spells, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.

| Druid Level | Spells |
| --- | --- |
| 3rd | *spike growth*, *locate animals or plants* |
| 5th | *plant growth*, *summon fey* |
| 7th | *conjure woodland beings*, guardian of nature* |
| 7th | *tree stride*, *wrath of nature* |

#### Natural Energy

Starting at 2nd level, you are surrounded by invisible orbs of natural energy. After a long rest or meditating for at least 1 hour, you regain 1d4 expended orbs. You can have no more than 10 orbs at any one time, which increases to 15 at 5th level and 20 at 10th level.

As a bonus action, you may expend 8 of these orbs to recover an expended 1st-level spell slot. Starting at 5th level, you can expend 10 orbs to recover an expended 2nd-level spell slot. Starting at 7th level, you can expend 12 orbs to recover an expended 3rd-level spell slot. Starting at 11th level, you can expend 14 orbs to recover an expended 4th-level spell slot.

#### Voice of Nature

Starting at 2nd level, you imbue plants within a 100-foot radius of you with limited sentience and awareness. You are capable of simple communication through emotions with the affected plants. This means they can feel your happiness, annoyance, excitement, anger, sadness, and pain; and you can feel theirs.

Because of this emotional connection, you take on some of the characteristics of plants: your skin takes on the a bark-like appearance and your speed is decreased by 15 feet. Whenever you are angry, some plants cause damage to creatures touching them:

- Plants that are restraining creatures other than you cause them to take 1d4 piercing damage when the creature begins its turn restrained.
- Plants that are creating difficult terrain cause creatures other than you that move into or move within that area for the first time each turn to take 1d4 piercing damage.

This damage increases to 1d6 at 6th level, 1d8 at 10th, and 1d10 at 14th level.

#### Nature’s Wrath

Starting at 6th level, your connection to nature grants you occasional bursts of power. As an action, you can expend 12 of your orbs and expend a use of Wild Shape to channel the energy of the surrounding area. Instead of transforming into a beast, you take on the form of an awakened tree. Your size is Large for the duration of this form, and you gain additional benefits:

- Your speed is increased by 20 feet.
- Add half your Wisdom modifier to attack rolls you make, rounded down.
- Whenever damage is rolled for due to one of your spells, abilities, or attacks, add an additional 1d4, maximum once per spell/ability/attack. (For example, if nearby plants are creating difficult terrain, you will roll an additional 1d4 piercing damage every time your Voice of Nature feature causes those plants to roll for damage. The same is true for a spell like *ensnaring strike*, which will cause an affected creature to take damage from *ensnaring strike*, Voice of Nature, and the additional 1d4). This additional damage increases to 2d4 at 10th level, and 3d4 at 14th level.

#### Enhanced Connection

Starting at 10th level, you regain 1d6 orbs instead of 1d4 orbs after finishing a long rest or meditating for 1 hour. In addition, you can use your action to expend 20 orbs and immediately cast the *awaken* spell without material components. It still requires the same amount of time to cast. When you cast *awaken* in this way, it can only target plants.

#### I Am Groot

*(I couldn’t think of what to call this ability)*

Starting at 14th level, when your Nature’s Wrath feature is active, you add your full Wisdom modifier to your attack rolls, instead of half your Wisdom modifier. In addition, your connection to nature has transformed your body more: some leaves sprout from your head, and your barky skin gives you +2 AC.

Comment: Hello Niv Mizzet! Interesting ideas, especially as a lover of all things Treebeard! Go ahead and look over [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/64464) to see what sort of things we look for in homebrew-review questions. Specifically, what are the goals of the subclass? Of each of the subclass's abilities? What, if anything, have you tried already, and how did that go? If you edit in that information, that will help us a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the information ESCE, I will be posting a follow up question that is updated with more complete information shortly 

Comment: Only comment is that they 'rouse' plants rather than 'arouse' them. Or at least I hope!

Answer (score 1):

## This feels all around awkward and doesn't seem particularly fun to play

I'll go through things feature by feature:

#### Circle Spells

Nothing really special here. This is the same as the Circle of the Land feature.

#### Natural Energy

This feature just seems like a clunky effort to duplicate the Circle of the Land's Natural Recovery feature. Indeed, I'm inclined to wonder why this isn't just Natural Recovery given that the overall goal appears to be to allow the Druid to recover spell slots during the day.

There are some differences, presumably to allow these druids to be notably different:

- Spell recovery is limited 4th level slots
- Druid is able to utilize the feature multiple times in the day in a fashion similar to a Warlock's Pact Magic feature (i.e. can keep recovering energy without a long rest), but is overall less reliable because the recovery is randomized (i.e. 1d4).

Presumably these differences were chosen to give make the druid different, but honestly it's just clunky and seems likely to just cause confusion given there are better designed features that are already doing 'almost' this. Furthermore, this means that the druid can't regularly know what their class features are going to do because the recharge method is similar to a magic item.

I'd scrap this entirely and just crib the language from Natural Recovery and call it a day.

#### Voice of Nature

The first question I have to ask is, "And what happens when we're on a mountain/desert/city/underwater?"

The second question is, "Do you hate small races?" As written, this feature is going to drop a halfling druid's speed from 25 feet to 10 feet. Furthermore, as written, this is all the time.

Overall, you've got a feature, which is presumably intended to synergize well with the *[entangle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle)* spell, but you haven't really created a manner for which the druid can reliably use that spell. It's not even freely available to the druid via Circle spells.

I would recommend that you re-write this so that it addresses the following:

- Gives the druid a means to always have the entangle spell prepared.
- Keep your ribbon ability regarding communicating with plants, but maybe generalize it down to just 'empathize with them'.
- Eliminate the speed reduction altogether or at least tie its occurrence to the druid using the feature to damage others.
- Consider re-writing the damaging elements to allow the druid to exclude friendly creatures. Indeed being able to drop an entangle and having your allies automatically succeed could let this druid be a pretty neat support caster.

#### Nature’s Wrath

Again, this is very complicated to implement and I'm unsure why. For some reason you're trying to mix resources between the orbs you've created and the druid's wild shape uses. This is going to be a paperwork hell to keep track of.

On top of that, I'm also not sure what you're trying to do, either. Are you trying to let people turn into plants or stack the general effect of 'plants stab you more'? Or are you trying to undo the speed penalty from the Voices of Nature feature?

If the former, then maybe instead make this feature which allows the character to Wild Shape into plants, thereby lifting the restriction of 'just beasts' and changing the CR calculation for plant creatures to be 1/3 druid level similar to Circle of the Moon's Circle Forms feature. There's apparently 43 plants listed on D&D Beyond, it'd be cool to see some of them used be a plant druid.

If you're instead shooting for 'plants stab you more', you're probably better off just trying to work that into the Voice of Nature feature with something that scales by level.

#### Enhanced Connection

This seems likely to be a scenario wherein either the character is going to have a forest following them around on a regular basis or they're deliberately hamstringing themselves because it'd be incredibly easy to have a forest following you around with the way this is written. You may want to look at the Command Undead feature for necromancer wizards for a better way to address a feature that's likely to create a long-term companion.

#### I Am Groot

For a 14th level feature, this seems pretty terrible. The [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) cantrip already lets you do what the first half of this feature is proposing.

As for the second half, you're giving the druid +2 to AC. While this isn't terrible, it's not exactly great either. The version of this class that you'd written, this druid doesn't come off as the type to be regularly drawing attacks. There may be ways to re-write this class so that it's more tanky, but if that's the case, I'd probably suggest that instead something along the lines of allowing the druid to have the *[barkskin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/barkskin)* spell on all the time and without concentration. This would provide some always-on protection that easily moves through forms.