# What should I change for my homebrew Ent subclass? (Updated)

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, druid, homebrew-review, archetype

This is a follow up question to my earlier post: [What changes should I make to improve my homebrew Circle of the Ent druid subclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188180/what-changes-should-i-make-to-improve-my-homebrew-circle-of-the-ent-druid-subcla)
The changes made in this post are designed to make it more clear what my goals with this custom subclass are, and to incorporate the feedback I did get on the original post.

**What is it?**
This is a homebrew Druid Circle inspired by the Ents from *Lord of the Rings* (LOTR)
My goal is for this Druid Circle to have the following characteristics:

- Lots of synergy with spells such as Entangle, Spike Growth, Plant Growth, Grasping Vine, Ensnaring Strike, and any other effect involving plants that restrain, slow, or otherwise hinder enemies.
- A character that is on a day-to-day basis at somewhat of a disadvantage (slowed, slightly weaker abilities than some of the other Druids), but can every so often unleash its accumulated power with devastating force (such as the anger of Treebeard in LOTR).
- A character that has a “reservoir” of energy that regenerates over time or through certain actions. This energy can be expended for a variety of things: recovering spell slots, casting certain spells, and is needed to activate the Ent rage-mode mentioned above.
- This subclass can’t work as well when there are no plants, which means it is somewhat limited to campaigns with some plant presence at least a portion of the time. While not ideal if you want to run this character in a campaign spending a lot of time in a place with 0 plants, it is thematically fitting for the Ents.
- I would love to test this out but unfortunately do not currently have a group I can play dnd with :(

With all of that said, that brings me to the feedback I’m hoping for:

- Overall, how does it compare to other Druid Circles. More powerful? Less powerful?
- What of these ideas need concept improvement, modification, or simplification?
- What of these ideas work well or are a cool concept, if any?
- What abilities need to be made more powerful/less powerful. Initially I made sure to lean more on the side of a little weaker, but I may have gone overboard now, I’m not sure.

Below is the full info (changes made since first post)

===========================

**Path of the Ent (Druid Circle)**

*Druids of the Path of the Ent Circle are attached to the nature around them in everything they do. They feel what the plants feel, and the plants feel what they feel. They are capable of arousing plants to fight but must be careful since they will feel some of the harm done to any plants.
Because of their abnormally deep connection with plants, Path of the Ent Druids take on many of their characteristics including appearance, movement, and a steadier world view.*

Your understanding of the flora around you and deeper connection to and awareness of the living world grants you access to certain spells.

At 3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th level you gain access to the spells listed for that level in the table below. Once you gain access to one of these spells, you always have it prepared, and it doesn't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.

**Additional Spells**
3rd——————Spike Growth, Locate Animals or Plants
5th——————Plant Growth, Summon Fey
7th——————Conjure Woodland Beings, Guardian of Nature
9th——————Tree Stride, Wrath of Nature

**Natural Energy**
Starting at 2nd level, you have a reservoir of nature-based energy. You regain 1d4 energy after a long rest, short rest, or meditating for at least 1 hour. You can have no more than 10 natural energy at any one time, which increases to 15 at 5th level and 20 at 10th level. This energy can be expended for multiple uses. Starting at 2nd level, you may use an Action to expend 6 energy and cast the Entangle spell, a maximum number of times per day equal to your proficiency bonus. You always have this spell prepared, and it doesn’t count against the spells you can prepare each day. Additionally, you can expend energy to regain spell slots. To do this you may, as a bonus action, expend 8 energy + 2 energy for each spell level above 1st to recover an expended spell slot of that level.

*Goal of the ability:*

- create what is essentially a resource that can provide benefits but needs to be carefully managed. This energy gains additional uses later.
- give constant access to Entangle, which is a highly synergistic spell with this Circle.
- create a way to regain spell slots, but slightly worse that a Circle of Land Druid’s ability that achieves the same thing.

**Voice of Nature**
Starting at 2nd level, plants in a 120 foot radius of you have limited sentience and awareness. You are capable of sensing what each other are feeling. Because of this mental connection, you take on some characteristics of plants: you skin takes on a bark-like appearance and your speed is decreased by 10 when you are not wildshaped as a beast. These effects continue regardless of whether or not you are currently around plants. Whenever you are angry, this connection causes some plants to do damage to creatures touching them:

- Plants and magically created plants that are restraining creatures cause them to take 1d4 piercing damage when the creature begins its turn restrained.
- Plants and magically created plants that are creating difficult terrain or are otherwise effecting the movement or speed of creatures do 1d4 piercing damage to a creature the first time it moves into or within an affected area during its turn.
  You may exempt any number of creatures of your choice from  this damage, as well as from plant-caused effects that reduce speed.
  These damages increase to 1d6 at 6th level, 1d8 at 10th, and 1d10 at 14th level.

*Goal of the ability:*
*First part:*

- Creating a disadvantage for this subclass in the form of slow speed and feeling the pain of plants
- Allowing basic communication with surrounding plants.
  *Second part:*
- creating synergy with the many plant-based spells that hinder enemies.
- This creates additional synergy with the extra damage rolls from when the ability Nature’s Wrath is active.

**Nature’s Wrath**
Starting at 6th level your connection to nature grants you occasional bursts of power. As an action, and only when you have 15 or more energy, you can expend a use of Wild Shape to channel the energy of the surrounding area. Instead of transforming into a beast, you take on the form of an awakened tree. (*Once activated, this form ends after 10 minutes or when you use Wildshape. If you expend energy and drop below the 15 energy required to activate Nature’s Wrath, it does not end it*). When Nature’s Wrath ends, remove all energy you have. Your size is large for the duration of this form, and you gain additional benefits:

- Your speed is increased by 20.
- Add half your Wisdom modifier to attack rolls you make, rounded up.
- Whenever you roll for damage for an attack, add an additional 1d8, which increases to 1d10 at 10th level and 1d12 at 14th level.
- Whenever a damage roll is made because of your ability Voice of Nature, add an additional 1d6. (For example, if nearby plants are creating difficult terrain, you would roll an additional 1d6 every time Voice of Nature causes those plants to damage a creature. The same is true for a spell like Ensnaring Strike, which will cause an affected creature to take damage from Ensnaring Strike, Voice of Nature, and the additional 1d6). This increases to 1d8 at 10th level and 1d10 at 14th level.
- During the duration of Nature’s Wrath, the Ensnare spell you have prepared from your Natural Energy ability has the following change: it does not require concentration to maintain. You can end the spell at any time, it still requires the 6 energy to cast with the Natural Energy ability, and you cannot cast it multiple times while one is still maintained.

*Goal of the ability:*

- The equivalent of the Ents anger from LOTR.
- Temporary, can only be used occasionally, not every day. It is the pay off for normally being a slow, slightly weaker character.
- Increased speed, attack, and damage.
- Additional synergy with the Voice of Nature ability, doubling up the damage done.
- Allow you to temporarily cast Entangle in additional to another, normally cast spell that involves concentration. This might be too powerful all things considered, but it is a feature I want to have something like in the final form of this homebrew.

**Enhanced Connection**
Starting at 10th level, you regain 1d6 energy instead of 1d4 energy after short rests, long rests, and meditating. In addition, you gain access to the Awaken spell and the Commune with Nature spell. Up to once per day you can use your action to expend 8 energy and cast Commune with Nature or to expend 20 energy and cast the Awaken spell without paying its physical components. It still requires the same amount of time to cast. When you cast Awaken this way, it can only target plants. You can only cast this spell if there is currently no more than 1 other plant charmed by this effect. You always have these spells prepared, and they don’t count against the spells you can prepare each.

*Goal of the ability:*

- Increase the rate of regenerating energy
- Provide an additional spell, which can be used to assemble a small army of walking trees (up to 2 can be charmed by the spell at the same time, but after they are no longer charmed they might choose to remain with you).
- An additional use for energy that can track down nearby problems.

**I Am Groot** (I couldn’t think of what to call this ability)
Starting at 14th level, when your ability Nature’s Wrath is active, you add your whole Wisdom modifier to your attack rolls instead of half, and can make an additional attack each time you use the attack action. In addition, any number of creatures of your choice have the following benefits when in an area of heavy foliage or plant-caused difficult terrain:

- Advantage on Stealth checks
- Regain 2d6 HP whenever they begin a turn in such an area
  Creatures you have not allowed those benefits have disadvantage on Strenth checks and Strength saving throws while in those areas.

*Goal of the ability:*

- Grant benefits for allies being in the area of a spell like Entangle or Spike Growth
- Create additional issues for enemies in the area of such spells, specifically by giving disadvantage on the checks and saving throws needed to escape many of these spells.

If you read all the way down here, thank you so much for taking the time to read all of this and I look forward to seeing your thoughts :)

Comment: Please edit the original question with clarifications instead of asking a new question to skirt around the closure.

Comment: I was told via a link provide to: “ Iterate in follow-up questions, not by editing the same question.

If you want to incorporate feedback, but still want review on your material, then post a new follow-up question with the updates.” I don’t appreciate having my post closed for the second time after following the instructions laid out before me. This wasn’t me “skirting around the closure” this was me literally doing exactly what I was told.

Comment: In addition to the link provided by ESCE instructing me to post a new question with the edits made, as part of the note about the post being closed I was told I could “edit the question or post a new one”. Again, I really do not appreciate my post being closed despite doing exactly what I was supposed to.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair enough. That sentence though is in relation to follow-up iterated versions of the homebrew. I.E. once the 1st version of the homebrew has gotten a few answers and you've taken the time to "playtest" them *then* you post the 2nd version of the homebrew as a new question. Clarifications to the 1st version *should* be edited into the original question, *not* posted as a new question. As for the "edit or post a new one" notice, yeah, that doesn't do a great job of explaining things.

Comment: We’ve got a rule: you must wait 72 hours before posting follow up questions on homebrew review. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/62294) for more details.

Comment: I will say that the prompt to ask a new question is often actively unhelpful like it has been in this case: It actually *suggests* an action that skirts around closures and makes more work for site members. People are well aware of this and have [requested that the phrasing be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951) but it's currently just deferred for who knows how long. Apologies for the site's own mistake and especially how these closures may have felt given that mistake

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, what should I do from here? Both of my questions have been closed

Comment: Why does turning into a tree increase your speed?  I would make it decrease your speed if anything, like the guardian ranger's transformation.

Comment: Good question qazwsx! The idea I had for that was more a walking tree/awakened tree, like an Ent. So arms, legs, and very angry about people disturbing the forest